# Laravel 4: Using Auth::attempt with fields from different tables

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I have a table User and a table Profile. The Profile table has among others the profile name (or username) of the User. The password is stored in the User table. How can I authenticate the User with username/password, using the Auth::attempt method? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have username and password in the same table to use default `Auth` methods. Otherwise you will need to write your custom Auth class that will check it in 2 separate tables.

To be honest it's very strange that you have password in one table and username in other table. I've never do that. Even if I had profile and user in separate tables I had in both tables username.